# Grails promises are not executed reliably

Tags: grails

The project uses Grails 2.3.11

This code should print exactly 100 lines:

```
(0..99).each { i ->
  Promises.task {
    println("i = $i")
  }
}
```

But this doesn't happen.
I see different number of printed lines every time.
Seems like some promises are eaten.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're experiencing the issue but maybe GPars is more reliable e.g.

```
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

GParsPool.withPool{
    ( 0..99 ).eachParallel{ i ->
        println "i = $i"
    }
}
```